# Angular: Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Lambda not supported

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-providers, angular-factory, angular-dependency-injection

In my Angular app, I'm trying to use a [factory provider](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers) in my module:

```ts
export function getMyFactory(): () => Window {
  return () => window;
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: WindowRef, useFactory: getMyFactory() },
  ],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

but this is failing with:

> Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'MyModule':
>
> Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Lambda not supported

Answer (score 23):

I've found an easy solution reported on a thread from GitHub: [Arrow lambda not supported in static function](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/696#issuecomment-387114613) posted by [haochi](https://github.com/haochi)

The solution is basically:

> assigning the result to a variable, then return the variable

---

So in my case, I've resolved by replacing:

```ts
export function getMyFactory(): () => Window {
  return () => window;
}
```

with:

```ts
export function getMyFactory(): () => Window {
  const res = () => window;
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Just add the `// @dynamic` comment like this:

```
// @dynamic
export function getMyFactory(): () => Window {return () => window;}
```

More info in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#strictmetadataemit)

Answer (score 6):

This same error happened to me in an Angular library.

I ignored it by setting `"strictMetadataEmit": false,` in `tsconfig.lib.json` under `angularCompilerOptions`.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to return a promise as a function, and replaced this:

```
export function myFunc(): Function {
    const result = () => ...
    return result;
}
```

With:

```
export function myFunc(){
    const result = () => ...
    return result;
}
```